# Customize Invoice - Add email to ship to area

Tags: custom, invoice

I am attempting to add the customer email address to "address information"  area of the invoice.  Under Bill To information would be great.  Essentially adding email under telephone number.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to override this file

> vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\view\info.phtml

to your theme

> app/design/adminhtml/vendor/theme/Magento_Sales/templates/order/view/info.phtml

and by this code, you will get the customer email from the order object

```
$order->getShippingAddress()->getEmail();
```

hope this will help you